# trace() error "can only be used inside a tracked computed value or a Reaction" when used inside computed

Tags: mobx

I've used MobX for a few years now, and love it, but sometimes my trace calls are not functioning, and I don't understand why not. There must be some fundamental thing that I've completely misunderstood, but most likely have been lucky enough to get through anyway. Here's an example of using `trace()` where I'm getting an error:

```
import { computed, observable, trace } from "mobx";

class Stat {
  @observable baseValue = 1;

  @computed get value() {
    trace();

    return this.baseValue;
  }
}

const strength = new Stat();

strength.baseValue = strength.baseValue + 1;
```

The expected output, in my mind, is that trace reacts to the change in "baseValue" and logs the change. Instead, I'm getting the following error:

> Error: [MobX] 'trace(break?)' can only be used inside a tracked computed value or a Reaction. Consider passing in the computed value or reaction explicitly

"Inside a tracked computed value" is, to my understanding, exactly what I'm doing. Or..?

Full sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-trace-trouble-ki2qj?file=/index.ts:0-312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand this phrase

> inside a **tracked** computed value or a Reaction.

you need to access computed value inside reactive context, like inside `observer` or `reaction` or `autorun`. Otherwise `trace` just don't have information about what is going on because your computed value is untracked at that moment by any observer.

So this will work:

```
const MyComponent = observer(() => {
    return <div>{strength.value}</name>
})
```

or this

```
autorun(() => {
  console.log(strength.value);
});
```